# Removing the title from slide

Tags: header-footer, titles

I am trying to make a presentation. I want to remove the very long title which appears as the footer of every slide. How do I do it? I have used the following code.

```
\documentclass[english,svgnames,notes=hide,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}

\def\presentationtitle{Asymptotic symmetries at timelike infinity}

\title{\large\presentationtitle}
\author{Aniket Khairnar}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Why?}
\begin{itemize}
\item Reason for studying asymptotic symmetries.
\item Study of BMS group at null and spacelike infinity.
\item Statements on massive particle soft theorems
\item Holographic principle

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add an empty value for the short title option: `\title[]{\large\presentationtitle}`